# $resource.get() throwing function not found error

Tags: ionic-framework, ngresource

I am new to ionic and this is my factory file code

```
 .factory('getLocations', ['$resource', 'constants', function ($resource,      constants) {
return $resource(constants.server + constants.routes.getLocation, {id : '@id'});
  }])
```

here the url is like ../rest/search/:id

and the call from controller is as below :

```
$scope.locations = getLocations.get({id : '1'});
```

but then i call the rest URL, I am getting below error in my console :

```
 ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: V is not a function
at http://localhost:8100/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js:13:165
at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13704:18)
at C.setUrlParams (http://localhost:8100/lib/angular-resource/angular-      resource.min.js:13:50)
at Function.l.(anonymous function) [as get  (http://localhost:8100/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js:10:156)
at Scope.$scope.loadLocations (http://localhost:8100/js/searchController.js:80:39)
at fn (eval at compile (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27643:15),<anonymous>:4:230)
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30400:28)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:37225:13
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:39989:9
at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13696:20)
(anonymous) @ ionic.bundle.js:26799
(anonymous) @ ionic.bundle.js:23512
(anonymous) @ ionic.bundle.js:39991
```

What am I missing? I am passing the parameters as defined in the url still this error is shown. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. It was an issue with the way I had configured my factory file.